# Error AS-->You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',

Tags: mysql

I have created my first database name "Enote" and database table name "user"
[image]

*And i want to create another table with same database name "**Enote**" and but another database table name ="**post**" but i'm not able to create table as show below :*

```
create table post
 (id int not null auto_increment,
 title varchar(45) not null,
 content varchar(45) not null,
 date timestamp null default,
 uid int not null
 constraint uid primary key (id)
 foreign key (uid) references user (id)
 on delete cascade
 on update cascade);
```

following is the error what i get while creating table "**post**":[image]

Comment: You are missing some `,` in your sql syntax, near `uid`.

Comment: Even though i've used    , still it gives same error;                                                                                                          create table post
     (id int not null auto_increment,
     title varchar(45) not null,
     content varchar(45) not null,
     date timestamp null default,
     uid int not null,
     constraint uid primary key (id)
     foreign key (uid) references user (id)
     on delete cascade
     on update cascade);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your query.

First of all your `date` should be :

```
`date` timestamp    NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or

```
 `date` timestamp  null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

And you are missing some `,`.

You can try:

```
 create table post
 (id int not null auto_increment,
 title varchar(45) not null,
 content varchar(45) not null,
 `date` timestamp    NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 uid int not null,
 constraint uid primary key (id),
 foreign key (uid) references user (id)
 on delete cascade
 on update cascade);
```

[image]

Edit: Image for my comment explanation
[image]

Comment: Although i have created a database but date is not inserting  in database:                                     it's value remain null .

Comment: As data inserted in database parallely, the date should be also updated . Is it possible??