# MySQL ALTER Table query not working. Default Null, on update current timestamp

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change the default value of column `updated_at`, which is a datetime type.  What i want is:

```
Allow Null =  True
Default = Null
On Update =  Current Timestamp
```

Here is my query attempt:

`ALTER TABLE billing_payment_flow MODIFY updated_at datetime(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)`

I run the query and then when i check the table, nothing has been changed?

Where did i go wrong in query?

Comment: Do you get an error message? You would expect to get an error or the change, unless you are changing a table on one database and checking on another

Comment: *I run the query and then when i check the table, nothing has been changed?* If the query execution does not produce an error then you forget to commit changes simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the query below. I expect that the problem occurs due to the size specifier `(6)` in your statement, this depends on the MySQL version you're using. If you want to use `DATETIME(6)` you need MySQL 5.7 or later.

```
ALTER TABLE `billing_payment_flow`
MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` DATETIME NULL
DEFAULT NULL 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

This works for me, tested it with the following script in MySQL 8.0:

```
CREATE TABLE `billing_payment_flow`(`ID` int, `updated_at` DATETIME(6));

INSERT INTO `billing_payment_flow`(`ID`) values(1);

ALTER TABLE `billing_payment_flow`
MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` DATETIME(6) NULL
DEFAULT NULL 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6);

UPDATE `billing_payment_flow` SET `ID` = 2 WHERE `ID` = 1;

SELECT * FROM `billing_payment_flow`;
```

Result:

```
ID  updated_at
2   2021-09-14 10:55:55.891703
```

Comment: I tried this, everything works except Default=NULL?  Right now it is showing `no default ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: `default=NULL` still not working using MySQL 8 but rest works.  Thanks

Comment: @user892134 check my answer if it helps with ne null: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68903731/error-as-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-correspon/68904257#68904257